# Finding the largest power of 2?

Tags: python

This is the code I created to find the largest power of 2 factor. I do not think that this is 100% correct because I keep getting 2 as the answer. I need some help figuring this out. I am completely new at programming.

MY CODE:

```
def largestPowerOfTwoThatIsAFactorOf(num):

    factor = 2

    while not(num > 0):

        factor = factor + 1

    return factor


print(largestPowerOfTwoThatIsAFactorOf(4))
print(largestPowerOfTwoThatIsAFactorOf(15))
print(largestPowerOfTwoThatIsAFactorOf(120))

#For any odd integer, largest power of 2 that’s a factor is 1.
```

Comment: `while not(num > 0)` means: "run the loop as long as the number is 0 or smaller". That's not gonna run the loop at all for positive numbers. For 0, it will execute the loop once and make the function return 3. That's not a power of two. You should **think about** an algorithm **before** hammering code blindly into the computer.

Comment: do not start from `factor = 2`

Comment: it's hard when you are a complete beginner, I try my best @TheParamagneticCroissant

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def largestPowerOfTwoThatIsAFactorOf(num):
    if num % 2 != 0: return 1
    factor = 0
    while num % 2 == 0:
        num /= 2
        factor += 1
    return 2 ** factor
    ## or return factor; as per your requirement
```

You need to update `num` inside the loop. Also, you cna optimize the code a little by checking whether the input was odd or not in the first statement.

Comment: `factor += 1` isn't gonna return a power of two. that's `factor *= 2`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant http://codepad.org/lbMCNgSP It is returning the powers of 2

Comment: I must be missing something but since when 3 is considered to be a power of two?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant The function is returning `n` where; `2^n` is the factor.

Comment: then it's returning the logarithm of a power of two.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting and useful function, fit to deal with FFT, to perform Signal Processing and Analysis once FFT is a square matrix with "power of two" dimensions... understanding that a power of two is the result of two elevated to some power, and that there are infinite powers of two greater than n, a better name to the function should be minimum power of two greater than n - we just use it to dimension a collection of signal data to submit it to FFT filter. There follows two options, named minpowof2 and the maxpowof2...

```
def minpowof2(n):
    '''Minimun Power of Two Greater Than n'''
    f = 1
    if n < 2: return 'try n greater or iqual to 2'
    while n > 2:        
        n /= 2
        f += 1
    return 2**f

def maxpowof2(n):
    '''Maximum Power of Two Lower than n'''
    return int(minpot2(n)/2)
```